# Rails test ok but when running with guard they fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest, guard

I've created a sample application with the issue here 
https://github.com/jean-francois-labbe/rails-guard-not-working

It's just a simple scaffolding with rails 5.1.4 and ruby 2.4.2

`rails g scaffold user username firstname creation:datetime
rails db:migrate
bundle exec rails test # => tests ok
bundle exec guard # => 3 tests will fail`

I've added `guard` and `guard-minitest` in the Gemfile.

Does anyone already encountered this issue?

**tests results below:**

```
~/Workspace/guard-tests-fail(master ✗) bundle exec rails test
Run options: --seed 23398

Running:

........

Finished in 0.649120s, 12.3244 runs/s, 15.4055 assertions/s.
8 runs, 10 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips


~/Workspace/guard-tests-fail(master ✗) bundle exec guard     
19:41:31 - INFO - Guard::Minitest 2.4.6 is running, with Minitest::Unit 5.10.3!
19:41:31 - INFO - Running: all tests
Run options: --guard --seed 38654

Running:

.....F

Failure:
MeetingsControllerTest#test_should_create_meeting [/home/jeff/Workspace/guard-tests-fail/test/controllers/meetings_controller_test.rb:19]:
"Meeting.count" didn't change by 1.
Expected: 3
  Actual: 2


bin/rails test test/controllers/meetings_controller_test.rb:18

F

Failure:
MeetingsControllerTest#test_should_destroy_meeting [/home/jeff/Workspace/guard-tests-fail/test/controllers/meetings_controller_test.rb:42]:
"Meeting.count" didn't change by -1.
Expected: 1
  Actual: 2


bin/rails test test/controllers/meetings_controller_test.rb:41

F

Failure:
MeetingsControllerTest#test_should_update_meeting [/home/jeff/Workspace/guard-tests-fail/test/controllers/meetings_controller_test.rb:38]:
Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <422: Unprocessable Entity>


bin/rails test test/controllers/meetings_controller_test.rb:36




Finished in 1.261359s, 6.3424 runs/s, 6.3424 assertions/s.
8 runs, 8 assertions, 3 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
19:41:35 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/home/jeff/Workspace/guard-tests-fail'
```

**Guard with same seed as rails tests**

```
~/Workspace/guard-tests-fail(master ✗) bundle exec guard
21:36:17 - INFO - Guard::Minitest 2.4.6 is running, with Minitest::Unit 5.10.3!
21:36:17 - INFO - Running: all tests
Run options: --guard --seed 23398

# Running:

...F

Failure:
MeetingsControllerTest#test_should_destroy_meeting [/home/jeff/Workspace/guard-tests-fail/test/controllers/meetings_controller_test.rb:42]:
"Meeting.count" didn't change by -1.
Expected: 1
  Actual: 2


bin/rails test test/controllers/meetings_controller_test.rb:41

..F

Failure:
MeetingsControllerTest#test_should_update_meeting [/home/jeff/Workspace/guard-tests-fail/test/controllers/meetings_controller_test.rb:38]:
Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <422: Unprocessable Entity>


bin/rails test test/controllers/meetings_controller_test.rb:36

F

Failure:
MeetingsControllerTest#test_should_create_meeting [/home/jeff/Workspace/guard-tests-fail/test/controllers/meetings_controller_test.rb:19]:
"Meeting.count" didn't change by 1.
Expected: 3
  Actual: 2


bin/rails test test/controllers/meetings_controller_test.rb:18




Finished in 1.397142s, 5.7260 runs/s, 5.7260 assertions/s.
8 runs, 8 assertions, 3 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
21:36:21 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/home/jeff/Workspace/guard-tests-fail'
[1] guard(main)>
```

**Steps to reproduce**

1) Just create a new project (rails new demo)

2) generate a scaffold (rails g scaffold user username)

3) rails test => rails test are ok

4) Add gem 'guard' and gem 'guard-minitest' in Gemfile. and run bundle

5) run guard init minitest.

6) bundle exec guard => and your tests will be failling

## stack traces

### rails test

```
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest/test.rb:107:in `block (3 levels) in run'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest/test.rb:204:in `capture_exceptions'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest/test.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in run'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest/test.rb:255:in `time_it'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest/test.rb:103:in `block in run'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:350:in `on_signal'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest/test.rb:275:in `with_info_handler'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest/test.rb:102:in `run'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:839:in `run_one_method'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:324:in `run_one_method'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:311:in `block (2 levels) in run'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:310:in `each'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:310:in `block in run'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:350:in `on_signal'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:337:in `with_info_handler'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:309:in `run'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/test_unit/line_filtering.rb:9:in `run'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:159:in `block in __run'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:159:in `map'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:159:in `__run'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:136:in `run'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:63:in `block in autorun'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:171:in `fork'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:171:in `serve'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
.rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
.rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

### Guard

```
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest/test.rb:107:in `block (3 levels) in run'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest/test.rb:204:in `capture_exceptions'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest/test.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in run'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest/test.rb:255:in `time_it'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest/test.rb:103:in `block in run'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:350:in `on_signal'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest/test.rb:275:in `with_info_handler'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest/test.rb:102:in `run'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:839:in `run_one_method'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:324:in `run_one_method'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:311:in `block (2 levels) in run'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:310:in `each'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:310:in `block in run'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:350:in `on_signal'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:337:in `with_info_handler'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:309:in `run'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/test_unit/line_filtering.rb:9:in `run'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:159:in `block in __run'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:159:in `map'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:159:in `__run'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:136:in `run'
.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:63:in `block in autorun'
```

Comment: What kind of failure are you seeing, exactly? Is it possible the two ways of running the tests require a slightly different set of files?

Comment: @hoffm I've added the tests results in the question

Comment: Could it be an order issue? Try running the tests with the same seed in both ways.

Comment: I added the guard results when executed with the same seed as rails test, still failing

Comment: My other thought is that they are using different configurations, i.e. `spec_helper.rb` or `rails_helper.rb`. Can you add some `puts` logging and see if you can find a difference in which files are being loaded or the order of loading when the tests boot up?

Comment: I added steps to reproduce in the question. I created a new project and had the same error. @hoffm thanks for the idea I had added database_cleaner gem to try it but removing it changed nothing.

Comment: The stacktrace are a bit different between rails test and guard. rails adds spring into the mix

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with `guard-minitest` and `spring`. Head to your `Guardfile` and add this `spring` command configuration to the initialization:

```
# Guardfile

guard "minitest", spring: "bin/rails test" do
  # ...
end
```

There is some semi-related discussion [here](https://github.com/guard/guard-minitest/issues/130). The `guard-minitest` README says that this is "due to complexities in how arguments are handled and running tests for selected files".